# Retrieve file names from flash file uploader

Tags: php, wordpress, flash, file-upload

I am using the flash uploader that comes with Quform for wordpress to allow up to 5 files. I am trying to retrieve the file names but i only ever get the first one. $filesA All the files upload without issue but I never get all the names.

Here is my code (php) I am using

```
$myfiles= $form->getValue('iphorm_x_x');
$filesA = $myfiles[0]['text'];
$filesB = $myfiles[1]['text'];
$filesC = $myfiles[2]['text'];
$filesD = $myfiles[3]['text'];
$filesE = $myfiles[4]['text'];
```

I only ever get the first file name. Not sure why or where it is going wrong

Many thanks
Patrick

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)`, and see how they showed up in PHP to begin with.

Comment: Many thanks. Using var dump I found the file names and i nneded to add a for each loop to retrieve them all

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer after using Marc B to get existing file names

```
$myfiles= $form->getValue('iphorm_x_x');
foreach ($myfiles as $file) {
    echo File Name: ' . $file['text'];
}
```

:)